# What redirect url is used for react-native-fbsdk?

Tags: java, facebook, react-native, fbsdk

I am building an app with react-native and currently I’m implementing `react-native-fbsdk` login.

All seems good, but I want to reuse returned `facebook` token in java back-end by calling java rest controller passing returned facebook token parameter. When I make request from java to url https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/oauth/access_token with facebook token returned from react-native app I get error:

> OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_code" "Invalid verification code format."

So I am thinking that this error occurs because of different `redirect_url` in my java beck-end (http://localhost:8000/) and react-native app (which I don’t know). But I can’t find where I can set up `redirect url` in  react-native fbsdk. Please, help me find out what I’m doing wrong.

Comment: No, a mismatched redirect_uri parameter would result in a different error. _“Invalid verification code format”_ means what it says - that the code you supplied was not valid. _“but I want to reuse returned facebook token”_ - token != code, those are different things. The login process results in a code, that your app then has to exchange for a token. If you _have_ a token already, then it does not make sense to go through that process again - just _use_ your token to make your API calls.

Comment: Thank you! I was passing access_token insted off authorization_code. Thats my bad